# Не берёт рандомные фразы из txt файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Написал бота, и через bot.send.message пытаюсь в чат отправить рандомные сообщения. А он отправляет одно сообщение рандомное, а потом по кругу пускает это же самое (в коде используется scheduler)

```
       bot.send.message(chat_id=***, text=randomLine)
       lines = open('test.txt',encoding="utf8").read().splitlines() 
       randomLine =random.choice(lines)
```

Comment: А где у вас изначально `randomLine` определяется? Так то вы просто переставьте местами команды - сделайте отсылку сообщения после случайного выбора, а не до.

Answer (score 1):

Да, я действительно невнимательно прописал команды, нужно было просто поменять их местами.....